# How to import GDAL embedded in new Fiona wheels

Tags: python, gdal, fiona

Since october 2022, Fiona's wheels include GDAL (according to [the releases documentations](https://github.com/Toblerity/Fiona/releases)). Many packages refer to GDAL using this command, but it won't work :

```
from osgeo import gdal
```

For instance, I've just loaded an environment using poetry (and python 3.9.15 on Linux) :

```
poetry new dummy
cd dummy
poetry add geopandas richdem
```

Calling this script will throw an error:

```
import richdem as rd
dem = rd.LoadGDAL("dummy")
```

> Exception: richdem.LoadGDAL() requires GDAL.

I don't think this troubles arises specifically from richdem, but it will be linked to any third package using `from osgeo import gdal`. Indeed, this is the command which is loaded in richdem's `__init__.py` file.

I also tried to load Fiona at first (as it patches GDAL environment variables at launch), but it doesn't change anything.

**Note :**

If I now install gdal (same version as the one included in my 1.8.22 Fiona, ie. gdal 3.4.3), then :

- `rd.LoadGDAL("dummy")` triggers a correct `RuntimeError: dummy: No such file or directory`
- `rd.LoadGDAL("a/real/tif_file.tif")` triggers a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_gdal_array'`

I think this is a distinct problem; besides, I now have two (same) distributions of GDAL on my pc, which can't be good.

**So the question is : how could I fix the `from osgeo import gdal` from third party packages calling for GDAL (if GDAL is embedded in Fiona) ?**

Answer (score 0):

Long story short : you can't simply switch from osgeo to Fiona.

In fact, Fiona doesn't includes GDAL python package (ie. the GDAL python bindings) but the shared library :

*From Sean Gillies :*

> Fiona's wheels contain a GDAL shared library (libgdal.dll or .so or .dylib) and its own library dependencies (libproj, etc). By GDAL, we mean the C library.

Beware also of trying to use both GDAL (ie. python bindings and Fiona) at the same time :

*From Sean Gillies :*

> It's not a great solution, I agree, and not only because you'll have two copies of libgdal. The Fiona project is not promoting it as a solution at all. In https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/switch.html#mutual-incompatibilities, I've warned users against this and I should probably do the same for Fiona to make it more clear.

More detailed info on [fiona.groups.io](https://fiona.groups.io/g/main/topic/95321716); following that discussion, an [issue](https://github.com/Toblerity/Fiona/issues/1166) was opened on github Fiona's repo.